# Append JQuery value to input field instead of select option

Tags: html, jquery

I have already append the JQuery value to the select option but I want to append value to an input field, any solutions?

Select option:

```
<select name="c_email" class="form-control" ></select>
```

JQuery value append:

```
$('select[name="c_email"]').append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ value +'</option>');
```

Instead of drop down select I want the value here in input field:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="c_email" placeholder="">
```

Comment: problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name="c_email"]').val(value);
```

And you can target that input with any of these, or all to be more precise:

```
$('input[name="c_email"][type="email"].form-control')
```

```js
var value="test";
$('input[name="c_email"]').val(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="c_email" placeholder="">
```